# JavaFXPorts - Changing scene results in Invalid Touch point ID error

Tags: javafxports, gluon-mobile

I have an app with 2 scenes. The app starts with the first scene (set to full screen mode), and when I tap a point on the screen, it then switches to the second scene (which is also set to full screen).

When I run it on Windows, it works fine. When I run it on Android, I get an error after switching to the second scene. The second scene pops up on the screen briefly and then crashes with the following exception in the logcat:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Platform reported wrong touch point ID
                                                             at javafx.scene.Scene$TouchMap.get(Scene.java:5455)
                                                             at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.touchEventNext(Scene.java:2716)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$null$361(GlassViewEventHandler.java:1148)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.access$lambda$20(GlassViewEventHandler.java)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$23.run(Unknown Source)
                                                             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleNextTouchEvent$362(GlassViewEventHandler.java:1127)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.access$lambda$17(GlassViewEventHandler.java)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$$Lambda$20.get(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:391)
                                                             at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleNextTouchEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:1126)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleNextTouchEvent(View.java:579)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyNextTouchEvent(View.java:1050)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.TouchInputSupport.notifyNextTouchEvent(TouchInputSupport.java:141)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.TouchInput.dispatchPoint(TouchInput.java:131)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.TouchInput.lambda$postPoint$82(TouchInput.java:155)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.TouchInput.access$lambda$3(TouchInput.java)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.TouchInput$$Lambda$4.run(Unknown Source)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.runLoop(RunnableProcessor.java:92)
                                                             at com.sun.glass.ui.monocle.RunnableProcessor.run(RunnableProcessor.java:51)
                                                             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Any suggestions on solving this would be great.

Here's the build.gradle file as requested:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

dependencies {
    compile project(':Util')
    compile files('D:/DevTools/minimal-json/minimal-json7.jar')     
    compile files('D:/DevTools/sqlite-jdbc/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.11.2.jar')       

    androidRuntime 'org.sqldroid:sqldroid:1.0.3'                
} 

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.8'
}
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.myapp.Client'

jfxmobile {

javafxportsVersion = '8.60.7'

android {
    manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
}
ios {
    forceLinkClasses = [ 'com.myapp.**.*', 'SQLite.**.*']
    infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you post your `build.gradle` script?

Comment: Hi Jose, I have included the build.gradle in the original posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your crash and I'll file a bug.

While on Desktop it is pretty common having several scenes or even stages, that's not the case on mobile.

Instead, we have one single stage, and we don't change the scene all the time, we just change its content.

Using Gluon Mobile, there are `View` nodes, that allow you precisely that: use as many views as you need to have different content, and switch between then when you need.

You can have a look at the GluonSQLite sample, that includes SQLite but it only has one View, or to other multi-view samples [here](http://gluonhq.com/support/samples/) like Notes or Comments.

Comment: Yeah, I have changed my app to now use a single Scene and am just switching between the scene's root nodes when I want to change the UI. There is also currently a bug in Java where if you switch scenes whilst in fullscreen, it kicks you out of fullscreen (whilst in desktop mode), so the scene switching mechanism doesn't look great right now until that bug is fixed.  Thanks for the help.